# scrollable div on swipe with jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am attempting to create a proper scrollable DIV that when swiped left or right will move along left and right.
I've done everything you would do with a basic page using CSS to create a horizontally scrollable DIV and I'm not finding much literature for jQueryMobile on that (or I'm looking in all the wrong places for it).

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up with something like this:

```
// jQuery Mobile's version of Doc Ready
$(document).bind('pageinit', function(){
    $('.div').bind('swipe', function(){
        // Your code here
    });
});
```

You can find the documentation here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html

Comment: So there is no inherent method to cause something like that to work?
Allowing scrolling in div via a swiping gesture that is.

Comment: No, it is better to instead support the `swipe` event and let developers decide what they want to do when that type of event fires.